# Making a List out of a Column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am Trying to make a list out of a certain Column of my DataFrame.

But it should depend on another column, if it schould be added to the list.

So for example if the dataframe is:

```
names <- c('Word1','Word2','Word3')
quant <- c(5, NA, 10)

my.data <- data.frame(names, quant)
```

Now I would only like to List the words with a quantity and leave out the ones with "NA".
Is there a smart and fast way to do this?
The final List in this case should be (Word1, Word3)

Thank you very much for your help. I am a beginner with R and my only soution would be a loop going through the dataFrame and check for every value.

Comment: ``na.omit(my.data)$names`` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `complete.cases`. `na.omit` removes all `NA`'s. With `complete.cases` we are able to partially select the columns. See  `my.data[complete.cases(my.data[1,1]),]` vs. `my.data[complete.cases(my.data[1:2,2]),]`:

```
my.data[complete.cases(my.data),]
```

```
  names quant
1 Word1     5
3 Word3    10
```

and is faster:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  na.omit(my.data)$names,
  my.data[complete.cases(my.data),]
)

Unit: microseconds
                               expr min    lq   mean median   uq   max neval cld
             na.omit(my.data)$names  46 46.95 50.457  47.60 49.4  90.9   100   b
 my.data[complete.cases(my.data), ]  22 22.80 25.522  23.65 24.3 133.5   100  a
```

Answer (score 2):

Or may use `subset` with `is.na` and negate (`!`)

```
 subset(my.data, !is.na(quant))
  names quant
1 Word1     5
3 Word3    10
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
na.omit(my.data)

  names quant
1 Word1     5
3 Word3    10
```